# Is it possible to use local storage to save navigation-drawer visibility?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vuetify.js

I have a navigation-drawer

`<v-navigation-drawer  ...content... </v-navigation-drawer>`

And a menu button, which hides/shows the navigation drawer.

`<v-btn @click.stop="drawer = !drawer"> Menu </v-btn>`

If I refresh / change page, I need to click the button to show/hide the navigation-drawer again. Is it possible to use local storage ...

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/client-side-storage.html

...to 'save' whether the navigation-drawer is hidden/visble?

I have checked the documentation / googled, but can not find out how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can simply use [localStorage](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/client-side-storage.html) to achieve this **:**

**Demo :**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    drawer: false
  },
  mounted() {
    const localStorageValue = JSON.parse(localStorage.drawer);
    this.drawer = localStorageValue ? localStorageValue : false;
  },
  methods: {
    setDrawer() {
     this.drawer = !this.drawer
     localStorage.drawer = this.drawer;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click.stop="setDrawer">Menu</button> <!-- replace this with vuetify v-btn component -->
  <div v-if="drawer">Show Me!</div> <!-- replace this with v-navigation-drawer component -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The link you provided has the necessary information, you need to read the drawer state from local storage when component is mounted and save it when the state changes

Call method `toggleDrawer()` in you @click handler instead of `drawer = !drawer` like this `@click.stop="toggleDrawer()"` or use a watcher on the drawer variable and update the localStorage when it's changed.

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    drawer: false
  },
  mounted() {
    // Read value from local storage
    if (localStorage.drawer) {
      this.drawer = JSON.parse(localStorage.drawer);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleDrawer() {
      this.drawer = !this.drawer;
      // Save value in local storage
      localStorage.drawer = this.drawer;
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the help - I am getting error `ReferenceError: drawer is not defined` , but I must be close to getting it working - I appreciate it

Comment: @qwerty654321 Fixed it, I missed a this in `this.drawer = !this.drawer`, try again.

Comment: I also spotted that :) ... I made the change and now It silently fails. It toggles the menu to hidden/visible, but does not save the state.

Its not something to do with this you think?
`
  data: {
    drawer: false (I have tried null)
  }

Comment: @qwerty654321 Use the browser inspector to look at the localStorage to see if the value is there, in Chrome it's under Inspector > Application tab > Local Storage. I also forgot that localStorage values are always strings so we need to parse the string to boolean using JSON.parse(localStorage.drawer) or  use Boolean(localStorage.drawer). I updated the code.

Comment: Yes, JSON.parse(localStorage.drawer) has solved my issue. The navigation-drawer state is now saved into local storage and everything works great. Thanks for your help.